# Animate dots or points from an offset to their actual position

Tags: jquery, css, html, svg

How can I do the animation by using SVG or CSS?

Animation should be like below:

Initially, only lines will be visible(***picture 1***), after 2 seconds dots (.) will come and join to the line curves(***picture 2***) with some animation to the dots.

### [Online Example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ts1zb1g7)

Please check the code below

**SVG Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         width="755px" height="390px" viewBox="0 0 755 390" enable-background="new 0 0 755 390" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
        <polyline fill="none" stroke="#777777" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="1" points="
            177.07,277.824 169.439,162.858 281.354,197.955 323.576,87.565 414.637,42.294 442.104,99.271 515.359,132.842 544.357,32.626 
            576.404,135.892 557.074,216.779 554.531,306.311 479.238,328.695 429.385,286.979 387.67,203.043 302.209,282.912 
            176.051,279.861 281.354,202.025 442.104,99.271 557.074,216.779 387.164,202.025 442.104,99.271 479.238,330.73 557.074,216.779 
            429.385,286.979 392.252,279.861 283.386,198.975     "/>
        <polyline fill="none" stroke="#777777" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="1" points="
            171.982,163.873 326.12,88.584 437.529,102.321   "/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <circle cx="177.07" cy="277.824" r="11.699"/>
        <path d="M479.238,316.996c6.463,0,11.705,5.236,11.705,11.699s-5.242,11.699-11.705,11.699c-6.459,0-11.699-5.236-11.699-11.699
            S472.779,316.996,479.238,316.996z"/>
        <path d="M323.576,64.674c12.643,0,22.892,10.254,22.892,22.891c0,12.648-10.249,22.893-22.892,22.893
            c-12.642,0-22.891-10.245-22.891-22.893C300.685,74.928,310.934,64.674,323.576,64.674z"/>
        <path d="M171.982,152.173c6.462,0,11.699,5.24,11.699,11.699c0,6.462-5.237,11.704-11.699,11.704
            c-6.463,0-11.699-5.242-11.699-11.704C160.283,157.414,165.519,152.173,171.982,152.173z"/>
        <circle cx="515.359" cy="132.842" r="11.699"/>
        <circle cx="281.354" cy="197.956" r="22.892"/>
        <circle cx="387.164" cy="202.027" r="18.315"/>
        <path d="M429.385,275.279c6.465,0,11.699,5.238,11.699,11.699c0,6.465-5.234,11.701-11.699,11.701
            c-6.461,0-11.699-5.236-11.699-11.701C417.686,280.518,422.924,275.279,429.385,275.279z"/>
        <path d="M392.252,266.631c7.302,0,13.223,5.922,13.223,13.23c0,7.303-5.921,13.225-13.223,13.225
            c-7.303,0-13.225-5.922-13.225-13.225C379.027,272.553,384.949,266.631,392.252,266.631z"/>
        <path d="M302.209,271.211c6.463,0,11.699,5.236,11.699,11.701c0,6.463-5.236,11.699-11.699,11.699
            c-6.464,0-11.699-5.236-11.699-11.699C290.51,276.447,295.746,271.211,302.209,271.211z"/>
        <path d="M442.104,76.378c12.643,0,22.891,10.243,22.891,22.893c0,12.638-10.248,22.891-22.891,22.891s-22.891-10.253-22.891-22.891
            C419.213,86.622,429.461,76.378,442.104,76.378z"/>
        <path d="M544.357,20.927c6.457,0,11.699,5.236,11.699,11.699c0,6.463-5.242,11.699-11.699,11.699
            c-6.465,0-11.705-5.236-11.705-11.699C532.652,26.164,537.893,20.927,544.357,20.927z"/>
        <circle cx="414.637" cy="42.294" r="11.699"/>
        <path d="M576.404,117.582c10.113,0,18.313,8.197,18.313,18.311c0,10.115-8.199,18.316-18.313,18.316s-18.316-8.202-18.316-18.316
            C558.088,125.779,566.291,117.582,576.404,117.582z"/>
        <circle cx="552.494" cy="306.821" r="22.892"/>
        <path d="M554.531,194.394c12.637,0,22.893,10.254,22.893,22.893c0,12.643-10.256,22.891-22.893,22.891
            c-12.645,0-22.893-10.248-22.893-22.891C531.639,204.648,541.887,194.394,554.531,194.394z"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

---

**Picture 1:** *(Default Screen)*

[image]

**Picture 2:** *(After Animation)*

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Atleast the SVG code for Picture 4?

Comment: Post the code what you have tried.

Comment: Hi **@Harry** and **@Jayababu** ... Thanks for your reply, I have updated the Actual SVG code with pics... As I am new to these technologies, if anybody can suggest simple suggestion it will be really great...

Comment: **@Harry**.. I have updated the code for Pic 2 (In my previous post it was Pic 4)

Comment: Add markers to the line. Make the markers visible via SMIL or CSS animation after 2 seconds.

Comment: Is it just me or is your "online example" just empty without code?

Comment: As I said... really sorry Guys, I dont have any clue about animation hence I have posted only svg code....

Comment: **@RobertLongson**, I need a animation to the dots which means dots has to come out of screen and slowly move to their location... Can I do that with CSS ?

Comment: @Reddy: Sorry, I thought you just wanted the animation. Do you mandatorily need it with CSS only?

Comment: **@Harry**, anything (CSS/SVG) is fine if animates :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using SVG

You can use `animateTransform` like in the below snippet. Basically what is being done is that initially the circle elements, cx and cy (center points) are translated in the Y axis (by 100px) and they are slowly animated back into their original position.

```css
polyline {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1;
  fill: transparent;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
    <polyline points='25,35 33,75 50,33 89,22 15,65' />
    <circle cx='25' cy='35' r='2'>
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="0 -100" to="0 0" dur="2s" />
    </circle>
    <circle cx='33' cy='75' r='2'>
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="-100 100" to="0 0" dur="2s" />
    </circle>
    <circle cx='50' cy='33' r='2'>
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="0 100" to="0 0" dur="2s" />
    </circle>
    <circle cx='89' cy='22' r='2'>
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="100 100" to="0 0" dur="2s" />
    </circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

If you have many such elements and want to do some kind of re-use of patterns or behaviors, you can make use of the `use` element like in the below snippet.

```css
polyline {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1;
  fill: transparent;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
    <defs>
      <g id='circle'>
        <circle r='2'>
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="0 -100" to="0 0" dur="2s" />
        </circle>
      </g>
      <g id='circle2'>
        <circle r='2'>
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="100 0" to="0 0" dur="2s" />
        </circle>
      </g>
      <g id='circle3'>
        <circle r='2'>
          <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" from="0 100" to="0 0" dur="2s" />
        </circle>
      </g>
    </defs>
    <polyline points='25,35 33,75 50,33 89,22 15,65 0,10 90,90' />
    <use x='25' y='35' xlink:href='#circle' />
    <use x='33' y='75' xlink:href='#circle2' />
    <use x='50' y='33' xlink:href='#circle' />
    <use x='89' y='22' xlink:href='#circle2' />
    <use x='0' y='10' xlink:href='#circle3' />
    <use x='0' y='10' xlink:href='#circle3' />
  </svg>
</div>
```

---

### Using CSS

If you mandatorily want to do it with CSS, you could put the polylines within one container `div`, the circular points within another and the animate the `div` with the circular points back into their position using `keyframes` and `transform`.

```css
polyline {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1;
  fill: transparent;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.points,
.lines {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.points {
  transform: translateY(100%);
  animation: movepoints 1s ease forwards;
}
@keyframes movepoints {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="lines">
    <svg viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
      <polyline points='25,35 33,75 50,33 89,22 15,65' />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="points">
    <svg viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
      <circle cx='25' cy='35' r='2' />
      <circle cx='33' cy='75' r='2' />
      <circle cx='50' cy='33' r='2' />
      <circle cx='89' cy='22' r='2' />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the above snippet would not work when the container is set to 100% `height` and `width` + the container's parent does not have a fixed height because we have absolutely positioned both its child elements. If you still want 100% `width` and `height` for the container, you can just position the `div` that contains the points alone using absolute positioning.

```css
polyline {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1;
  fill: transparent;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.points,
.lines {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.points {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.points {
  transform: translateY(100%);
  animation: movepoints 1s ease forwards;
}
@keyframes movepoints {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="lines">
    <svg viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
      <polyline points='25,35 33,75 50,33 89,22 15,65' />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="points">
    <svg viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
      <circle cx='25' cy='35' r='2' />
      <circle cx='33' cy='75' r='2' />
      <circle cx='50' cy='33' r='2' />
      <circle cx='89' cy='22' r='2' />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for your first rev, FF seems to only accept 2 values (x y) for `from` and `to` attributes with `type="translate"`

Comment: Yes it's because with rotate your defining (angle xOrigin yOrigin)

Comment: @Kaiido: You are correct. Just now found out that translate does need only two and updated :)

Comment: **@Harry**, If I am trying to use 100% width and height for the container it is not working... even if I removed overflow property...

Comment: @Reddy: It is because of absolute positioning of the elements within the container. Can you set some fixed height on the parent? If you can't then do like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ts0dotzd/).

Comment: **@Harry**... Is there any way that, I can target individual points instead of all points coming from bottom to top?

Comment: @Reddy: With the SVG `animateTransform` it is pretty easy (refer updated snippet where each of them come from a different direction. With CSS, you would have to put each circle inside a separate container which is tedious considering how many points you had in your code.

Comment: **@Harry**... Excellent.. with simple solution :) Thanks a Ton.. Keep up the great work

Comment: **@Harry**... Really Sorry for disturbing you again...
I have to do this for world map which has thousands of dots. Is there anyway to bring the same mechanism to all.. like array or something?

Comment: @Reddy: In SVG, you can make use of the `use` element like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3sz9dqb/1/) but if you want anything beyond that, you should check out some libraries like snap.svg.